# I'm stitching my way back in

Tags: phrase-meaning

I have heard the phrase *I'm stitching my way back in* multiple times, I did some research but couldn't find any entries.
What does this phrase mean?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense without context. It is possible that with suitable context it might make some sense.

Comment: Did you hear it in a song perhaps?

Comment: Although it does sound like _someone making their way back into a group or team_.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh Yes, most likely.

Comment: It does not sound familiar to me (US English speaker). Might be used regionally but is not common I don't think.

Comment: Does not sound familiar to me (British English). Perhaps it's a misheard version of 'making my way back (into the game)' or 'sticking in there' which are both idioms related to perseverance and tenacity.